# QGIS: Why do I get permission denied when saving style to postgres

Tags: qgis, postgresql

In QGIS I am trying to save a style to a postgres database but I always get the error "Unable to save layer style. It's not possible to insert a new record into the style table. Maybe this is due to table permissions (user=rful011). Please contact your database administrator."

The user has all rights on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message appears to be a generic failure message and does not mean that there was a permissions problem.  In my case the layer that I was trying to save the style of was composed by a complicated sql join and QGIS tried to use the whole sql query as the table name resulting in it overflowing the table name field.  It really should check -- I guess I will have to log a bug report.

As always if you get inscrutable messages in pop ups then look at the log for details.